# Ionic 2 this.nav.insert(0, Page);

Tags: ionic2

I have just upgraded from `Ionic 2 beta` to `Ionic 2 rc3`. I was using the following code, which doesn't seem to navigate to the new page (`MyPage`) in the `rc3` version.

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

    constructor(public nav: NavController...
        this.nav = nav;
        ...

        this.nav.insert(0, MyPage);
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: this.nav.push(MyPage)

Comment: Hi, but I don't want to push, because the page must be position 0 in the stack.

Comment: Describe the intended functionality clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to do:

   this.nav = nav;

It is injected in the constructor and is defined locally already.

2. Just setRoot()

   this.nav.setRoot(MyPage)

You could also do setPages()

```
this.nav.setPages([MyPage])
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/